# AngularJS navigate by service breaks when refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Still learning AngularJS. I have a setup where I load a subpage by choosing from a list on the main page. The pick is then stored in a service. Once the subpage loads it fetch that service value and use that info to lookup in another list. Problem is that if I reload the subpage the service resets and the pages gets displayed incorrectly because the service value has been reset as well..

Is there a good way to go around this? - I love code snippets as answer or link to them (easier to understand) :-)

I'm using auto reload when developing, so it becomes quite annoying sometimes.. I have to go back the main page and do a reload and navigate back.

Comment: There are 4 places you can store smth to recover it after refresh - url, cookies, local storage, server. Select one.

Comment: I just want to use an angular way of doing this.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thanks to you I found the ngCookies to solve my problem